# Cannot find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.NETCore.App' After publishing to IIS - .NET Core 2.1.1

Tags: iis, .net-core

I am facing an issue when I publish my .NET Core 2.1.1 app to IIS and this has started to happen after upgrading from .NET Core 2.1 to 2.1.1.

I am getting **Cannot find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.NETCore.App'**.

I tried to reinstall/uninstall/install the SDK 2.1.301 and the related runtime but no success.

This works fine on my dev PC but not on the IIS server.

Comment: This happens only when I call a method which relates to a class library based on .NET Standard 2.0. The rest of application works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed my issue by setting **MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish** to **false** in my **.csproj** file.